# How much computing resource is required to brute-force RSA?

Tags: cryptanalysis, public-key, rsa, brute-force-attack

It's been over 30 years since Rivest, Shamir and Adleman first [publicly](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf) described their algorithm for public-key cryptography; and the intelligence community is thought to have known about it for around 40 years—possibly longer.

It's fair to assume that, during those 40 years, certain three-letter organisations have employed their vast resources toward "breaking" RSA.  One brute-force approach may have been to enumerate every possible key-pair such that, upon encountering a message known to be  encrypted with a particular public-key, they need merely lookup the associated private-key in order to decrypt that message.  Signatures could be forged similarly.

How reasonable is this hypothesis?  How much computing resource would have been required over those 40 years to enumerate every possible {1024,2048,4096}-bit key-pair?  I think it best to avoid discussion and leave the question of whether the spooks could have harnessed such resource as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Would something have to have actually been tried to qualify as "having been an approach"? $\hspace{1 in}$

Comment: Even if you had infinite computing power you would not have the space to store all these public/private key pairs (I'll spare you the semimathematical posts comparing the space required to the number of protons in the universe). Many people have trouble perceiving just how big a number $2^{2048}$ is, it's a common error. A much more practical approach instead is to harvest as many real-life public keys as possible, and trying to find common factors between them. It actually works because of poor key generation practices.

Comment: Related question: [How many RSA keys before a collision?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-many-rsa-keys-before-a-collision)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's not possible.

The number of primes smaller than $x$ is [approximately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) $\frac{x}{\ln x}$. Therefore the number of $512$ bit primes (approximately the length you need for $1024$ bit modulus) is approximately:

$$\frac{2^{513}}{\ln 2^{513}}-\frac{2^{512}}{\ln 2^{512}} \approx 2.76×10^{151}$$

The number of RSA moduli (i.e. pair of two distinct primes) is therefore:

$$\frac{(2.76×10^{151})^2}{2}-2.76×10^{151}=1.88×10^{302}$$

Now consider that the [observable universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content) contains about $10^{80}$ atoms. Assume that you could use each of those atoms as a CPU, and each of those CPUs could enumerate one modulus per millisecond. To enumerate all $1024$ bit RSA moduli you would need:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1.88×10^{302}ms / 10^{80}&=&1.88×10^{222}ms\\
&=&1.88×10^{219}s\\
&=&5.22×10^{215}h\\
&=&5.95×10^{211} \text{years}
\end{eqnarray*}

Just as a comparison: the universe is about $13.75×10^9$ years old.

It's not a question of resources, it's simply not possible.

Also, it would not make any sense to do that. There are much faster ways to find out a secret key. In fact there are algorithms with sub-exponential running time for factoring integers.

Comment: You forgot to divide by 2 in your calculation. $\:$ Anyway, one can show rigorously (i.e., without using any approximations) that the number of possible 1024-bit RSA moduli is greater than $10^{302}$ (even when the primes must be distinct). $\;\;$

Comment: You made a typo at the first $10^{80}$ - a zero went MIA.

Comment: CAUTION: That does not accurately answer the _real_ question, which is in the title!

Comment: Still slightly off: 5.22e215 hours = 2.18e214 days = 5.96e211 years. (But +1 for having this available to reference.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 "Slightly" by two orders of magnitude. :D Fixed it. (though it's [5.95495](https://www.google.de/search?&q=5.22e215+hours+in+years), so 5.95)

Comment: Isn't it that the universe contains $10^{80}$ _proton masses_, not atoms?

Comment: @forest It's an upper bound on the number of atoms under the assumption that all atoms are hydrogen atoms. Clearly not all atoms are hydrogen (Apparently about 74% are.) so the number of atoms is even less than $10^80$. What's your point?

Comment: Just a nitpick I suppose, since you said atoms and not proton masses (aka atoms assuming everything is atomic hydrogen), which is a big difference. Your point still stands though, of course.

Comment: @forest Is it really a big difference though? Granted I'm no physiscist, but from what I can see the heaviest somewhat stable elements have their heaviest isotopes somewhere in the range between 200 and 300 proton masses. So even if all the atoms in the observable universe were Tennessine (a bit problematic, as the most stable isotope has a half life of 51 ms) with a mass of 294, the numbers would be off by only about 2 orders of magnitude. Which makes essentially no difference.

Comment: This is a valid argument that a dictionary of primes or factorizations can't help. It would however be wrong to conclude _on that ground_ that 1024-bit RSA is safe, even from classical computers. To evaluate that security, one must consider the best attack available, and the answer does not address that, thus does not address the interrogation in the question's title: _"How much computing resource is required to brute-force RSA?"_

Comment: @fgrieu The question in the question body is "How much computing resource would have been required over those 40 years to enumerate every possible {1024,2048,4096}-bit key-pair?" which is what's answered here. As the last  paragraph of the answer states, this has nothing to do with the security of 1024 bit RSA.

Comment: @Maher: Agreed, this does answer the question as in the body. And I have up-voted your answer.

Comment: It is not impossible ... are we limited to only classical computers? A quantum computer can break RSA with Shor's algorithm ... and we wouldn't need all the atoms in the universe ... only one building worth of atoms ... It's hard but not impossible

Comment: @Mustafa Shor's algorithm does not enumerate all n-bit primes, which was what was being asked.

Answer (score 15):

The brute force technique described in the question is hopeless, as pointed in this [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3044/555).

However there are much better techniques to attack RSA keys, including [GNFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve). Therefore 1024-bit RSA keys, even though they offer sizable security, can no longer be considered entirely safe from predictable academic efforts, or even safe at all from Three-Letter-Agencies. See my detailed [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1982/555) to [*How big an RSA key is considered secure today?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1978/555). And for new systems, use whatever recommendation is applicable, or refer to one of the many on this [site dedicated to keylength](http://www.keylength.com/) recommendations.

Also, sometime one can [exploit a goof in the key generator](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf), or attack RSA in ways that do not involve integer factorization: stealing the private key; extracting it by [Differential Power Analysis](http://www.cryptography.com/public/pdf/DPATechInfo.pdf), [Timing or Fault attack](http://cpe.kmutt.ac.th/lab/logic/Side_Channel_Attack.pdf); or taking advantage of a weakness in [padding](http://www.jscoron.fr/publications/padding.pdf). See also [*Twenty Years of Attacks on the RSA Cryptosystem*](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/RSA-survey.pdf).

Update: *Computational efforts* performed in the last 40 years help new attacks because the methods have been worked out, but (for any known practical method) *the computational effort* spent for attacking a particular key is not useful in attacking another key, much like knowing that $1234567890221=23801\cdot 51870421$ does not really help finding the factorization of $1234567890197$.

Comment: Thank you for all of the additional links - lots of very useful reading!  I suppose my perspective was whether due consideration had been given not only to the challenge of breaking RSA today from a zero-starting point, but had also factored in 40 years of effort?

Comment: @eggyal: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd really meant that once the factorisation you give has been discovered it can then be applied wherever the given product needs to be factorised.  Over forty years with vast computing resources, many such factorisations could be discovered.  I find [@Maeher's answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3044/971) more convincing in countering this argument, as it helps me to realise that the number of such factorisations required to be generated and stored even for 1024-bit RSA moduli is so vast that it is simply not reasonable even to hope for a collision with a known key.