# Why is it impractical to generate a semiprime dictionary?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

This might be a very simple question. However, I am just learning the concept, so just excuse me.

I am wondering why there is not any attempt to generate all semiprime numbers? (as an dict. attack to RSA-xxx algorithms). Because as far as I can see, all one is to do is as following:

1. get a database of prime numbers
2. multiply each prime number with each one. (which will require O(n^2) space)
3. save the product.
4. Of course, you will not do this for all of the prime numbers:)

   You will do this to prime numbers which will fall to the domain of RSA's random prime generator. In other words, which will create a $x$-bit number for RSA-$x$ (2048 bit for RSA-2048, for example).

I am sure one of these steps is impractical. Can you tell which one?

Comment: Hint: based on [this answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8671/555), compute how large your dictionary would need to be.

Comment: The problem is that there more than $2^{1000}$ primes that fall into the range of RSA-2048. Totally infeasible to find them all.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Oh, come on, that's only $2.743 \times 10^{279}$ [yottabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yottabyte)! (Just to store the semiprimes, that is. You'd need approximately double the space to store the factors too.)

Comment: @Reid no, you would need to store $2^{1999}$ multiples of those primes, which is quite a bit more. For each of them you would want both factors.

Comment: That's okay. I'm sure a few external hard drives will be more than enough... perhaps not.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: I was envisioning storing each 2048-bit semiprime plus the two factors, each around 1024 bits.