# WebCrypto SubtleCrypto RSA sign/verify AND encrypt/decrypt?

Tags: rsa

I have a project where I'd like to use public-key cryptography in both typical sign/verify situations *and* encrypt/decrypt situations.  For example, I'd like to create a self-signed X.509 certificate for Bob (certificate request containing `PubK.bob`, signed by `PrivK.bob` to form `Certificate.bob`), and I'd also like to conduct transactions like:

- Alice selects document key `DocK`, encrypts document `DocK[document]`, computes `PubK.bob[DocK]`, and sends `PubK.bob[DocK]` to Bob.
- Bob uses `PrivK.bob` to recover `DocK` from `PubK.bob[DocK]`, then decrypts `DocK[document]` to receive document from Alice.

However, the RSA keys that can be generated by `crypto.subtle.generateKey` (`RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5`, `RSA-PSS` and `RSA-OAEP`) can only be used for *either* `['sign','verify']` or `['encrypt','decrypt']` -- if you try to generate a key with all four usages, you get `Cannot create a key using the specified key usages`.

Is there a subtle crypto reason not to use a single RSA keypair for both sign/verify and encrypt/decrypt operations?

Is there a standard way of dealing with this?  A good way of doing it using WebCrypto?  (I can imagine putting an encrypt-capable public key into Bob's certificate, along with the verify-capable one, but that seems redundant, and also makes my certificates a little different from what other certificate-management tools are used to dealing with.)

Comment: This comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/choosing-which-is-public-vs-private-key suggests that encrypt and sign can't be treated as equivalent, which I think is what I'm proposing to do (letting Bob sign his certificate with `PubK.bob` _and_ letting Alice encrypt `DocK` as `PubK.bob[DocK]`.)  So maybe the answer really is "put Bob's public key for encrypting purposes into his certificate."

Comment: RSA is not for encryption. we prefer hybrid encryption. You can use RSA for Key Encapsulation Mechanism named [RSA-KEM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76857/18298).

Comment: Thanks for that link -- that's exactly what I want to do (transfer AES keys from Alice to Bob using asymmetric crypto).

Comment: For using one key, see [Using the same RSA keypair to sign and encrypt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12090/18298)

Comment: While there may be very good reasons to simply use two certificates / private keys for authentication and for encryption, I don't think it is the responsibility of an API to not allow you such use cases. There certainly have been certs / keys that would be able to be used to implement both - so I don't think you'll find anything in standards to that effect.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: FWIW rfc3279 (from 2002) 2.3.1 says "The use of
   a single [RSA] key for both signature and encryption purposes is not
   recommended, but is not forbidden" and describes KeyUsage values accordingly. I note 'recommended' there is not uppercase, although 3279 uses 2119's uppercase keywords extensively.. 
OTOH rfc4055 in 2005 uses distinct OIDs for PSS and OAEP, citing section 8 which says "[v1.5] has been employed for both key transport and digital
   signature without any known bad interactions, [but this] is not recommended in the future."